# Can anyone provide petfinder client_id?

Tags: php, laravel-8, petfinder

For my Laravel project I need to use petfinder site api access. But following instruction, whenever I am clicking on get an api button, it shows the page does not exist.

I am badly in need of the api, can anyone provide me any valid solution?  Or provide api.

Comment: Just show us the call you are making to the API and what the response is. Have you successfully got the API working with curl or command line tools?